# How to create an exception to grayscale(1) applied in header

Tags: html, css

I have a header in which are nested 2 divs (navigation) and one img (logo) element. I declared -webkit-filter: grayscale(1) in the header and it works well as expected applying grayscale to everything contained in the header. Only problem is I don't want grayscale applied to the logo. 
Have tried many options (none of which work):

- took logo out of the header (creates blank space)
- created a divaround the header & placed img within in but outside
  header(createsblank space)
- used a variety of selectors to isolate img such as `:not`    (no
  effect)

The html is:

```
<body>
<header>
  <nav class="navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#">news</a>
            </li>           
            <li>
                <a href="#">recipe</a>
            </li>   
            <li>
                <a href="#">event</a>
            </li>   
            <li>
                <a href="#">food</a>
            </li>   
        </ul>
    </nav>
        <img class="logo" src="images/main_logo_03.png" alt="main">  
</header>
```

The css is (note: am using flexbox):

```
   html , body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    header {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

    overflow-x: hidden;
    font-size: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 1%;


  background-image: url(../chateau-default3.jpg); 
  background-size: cover;  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
-webkit-filter: grayscale(1); 


  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-fixed-bottom {

    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px; 

    margin: auto;
  padding: 0;

 }

.navbar-nav > ul{

  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
} 

.logo{
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
max-height: 41%;
max-width: 41%;  
position: relative;
top: -7%;

}
```

How do i get .logo to be untouched by the grayscale - while keeping it in its position in the center of the header? (am only looking for application on chrome) Would appreciate insights.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround - took `.logo` outside the header and positioned it absolutely.